# Comparing Nodes in Binary Tree SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am given a tree constructor

```
tree(tip).
tree(bin(L,_,R)) :- tree(L), tree(R).
```

My task is to make sure that given a tree of Ints bin(L,X,R) holds true if every node in L is <= X and every node in R >= X. So I have come up with this solution and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Code:

```
bst(tip).
bst(bin(L,X,R)) :-
bst(L),
bst(R),
L <= X,
R >= X.
```

For example, a constructed tree:

```
?- bst(bin(tip, 3, bin(tip, 4, tip))).
```

is TRUE while

```
?- bst(bin(tip, 3, bin(tip, 2, tip))).
```

is false.

I am new to Prolog so any advice would certainly be helpful

NEW PART 2:

```
bst(tip).
bst(bin(L,X,R)) :-
    bst(L),
    bst(R).
bst(bin(L,X1,)) :-
    X1 =< X.
bst(bin(,X2,R)) :-
    X2 => X.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a good start there, but have a couple issues to work on.

First, I believe the operator for less-than-or-equal-to in SWI Prolog is `=<`, not `<=`.

Second, and more importantly, your comparisons `L <= X` and `R >= X` aren't going to work because the types don't match.  Your variables `L` and `R` are supposed to be trees, meaning that each is either `tip` or a `bin` term.  But the variable `X` is presumably a number (the data in a tree node).  Instead, you are going to need to examine the data part (the middle argument) of the Left and Right children of your tree node, and use that in your comparison.

Comment: I will add a new version of my code under my old question with my implementation of the advice you gave. I can't seem to get it working, but this is the only logical way I can see it working.

Comment: One key to learning Prolog is to stop yourself from thinking in terms of functions.  Your `getNode` looks like it is intended to be a function that takes a `bin` term and returns the middle part, which isn't how you want to think about solving this problem in Prolog.

Prolog is based on predicates and rules for when they are true or false.  Could you write a predicate that is true when a tree node and its parent are compatible with each other?  Perhaps you might want two predicates, one to check left children and one for right children.

Comment: For example, you might define a predicate that is true when a given `bin` term is a legal left child of a node with a given value.  This predicate would take two arguments: the child `bin` term and the parent's value.

Comment: I have updated it once again, however I am told it is bst/1. The code that I have come up with now I feel is on the right track, can you give me any further advice regarding my new code?